# Normalization + feature selection per fold in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I want to normalize and perform input selection on a dataset, BUT training and test set seperately (also in the case of 10-fold classification).

I already found that if I use the experimenter, I can add features selection like this:
-> simple -> Algorithms -> add new -> Meta -> AttributeSelectodClassifier.

It would be nice if an expert on Weka could confirm if the above method performs the attribute selection on the training set (not the full training + test set).

For the second part of my question. I have not yet found how to do this for the normalization. I know certain classifiers include normalization, but I am using multiple ones and not all of them have it. Can I put a normalization filter somewhere? My reviewer is asking this and I do not feel like doing the 10 folds manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question I asked at the weka forums: 
I do Meta-> FilteredClassifier and than as a classifier I choose Meta-> AttributeSelectedClassifier and then it should only normalize/feature select the training set.
[See reference.](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153046-Urgent-question-on-normalizaing-training-and-test-set-seperately&p=359201&posted=1#post359201)

Comment: if your answer solved your question, feel free to accept it. :)

Comment: I will , I have to wait 1-2 days to do so otherwise it is not allowed : ) Thanks for the reminder :)